# On interface method, can generic type param. be constrained to type implementing interface?

Tags: c#, generics, types, interface, constraints

I would like to know if the following can be accomplished in C#, but if you know of an alternate .NET path (F#, VB, etc.), I'd like to hear it also.

In an interface (or abstract class), on a generic method, I would like to have the generic type parameter of the method be constrained to the concrete class that is implementing the interface.

---

In pseudo-code the interface might look something like this:

```
interface Interface1<T> 
    where typeof(T) == this.GetType() //Illegal
{
    T Friend<T>();
}
```

---

This next variation compiles with a warning, "Type parameter 'T' has the same name as the type parameter from outer type 'Interface2'"

```
interface Interface2<T>
    where T : Interface2<T>
{
    T Friend<T>(); //The second 'T' will have the green warning underline.
}
```

---

The semantics of this pseudo-code define a less restrictive constraint than what I'm really looking for.  Classes implementing Interface1 should have to use themselves as type parameters,

```
class Class1 : Interface1<Class1> //Legal
class Class2 : Interface1<Class1> //Constraint violation
```

while classes implementing Interface2 can use any class implementing Interface2 as a type parameter.

```
class Class1 : Interface2<Class1> //Ok
class Class2 : Interface2<Class1> //Ok
```

---

An implementing class might look like this:

```
class Robot: Interface2<Robot> 
{
    private Robot friend;

    Robot Friend<Robot>() {
        return friend;
    }
}
```

This class will throw the compiler error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'MyNamespace.Robot' to 'Robot'", but if you qualify a few of the type names like this:

```
class Robot: Interface2<Robot> 
{
    private MyNamespace.Robot friend;

    MyNamespace.Robot Friend<Robot>() {
        return friend;
    }
}
```

It will change to "'MyNamespace.Robot' does not implement interface member 'MyNamespace.Interface2.Friend()'. 'MyNamespace.Robot.Friend()' cannot implement 'MyNamespace.Interface2.Friend()' because it does not have the matching return type of 'T'."

Is there a way to make Interface1?  Any reflection magic I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 1):

The following works:

```
interface Interface2<T> where T : Interface2<T>
{
    T Friend();
}

class Robot : Interface2<Robot>
{
    private Robot friend;

    public Robot Friend()
    {
        return friend;
    }
}
```

There is just no need to put the generic type on the `Friend` method.

Also, unfortunately, to my knowledge, there is no way to make `Interface1`.